# How to check if this make a non-increasing sequence or not.

Tags: c++

I was given a c++ task to receive a string of numbers. 
 
What I have to do is to move the first digit of that number into the last digit. 
 
for example if number is 1234 it should be 2341 like this. 
 
What I have also to do is to make the sequence of numbers non-increasing. 
 
For better understanding here is what I have to do: 
 
Input: 
 
1934 
7815 
1894 
6518 
3281

In the first sample, we will do the following moves:

```
1 move on x1 : 1934 -> 9341
1 move on x2 : 7815 -> 8157
3 move on x3 : 1894 -> 8941 -> 9418 -> 4189
2 move on x4 : 6518 -> 5186 -> 1865
3 move on x5 : 3281 -> 2813 -> 8132 -> 1328
The final sequence will be 9341 ≥ 8157 ≥ 4189 ≥ 1865 ≥ 1328.
```

If it's possible to make a non-increasing sequence like this, the program should print yes, otherwise I should print no. 
 
Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {


    string s[5];

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> s[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
            rotate(s[j].begin(), s[j].begin() + 1, s[j].end());

        }
    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++){
        while (s[j-1] <= s[j]){
                rotate(s[j].begin(), s[j].begin() + 1, s[j].end());



        }

    }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << s[i] << endl;
}
```

I did all the moves, then printed them, I don't know how to check if it is possible to make a non-increasing sequence or not. Also with my logic the while loop could be infinity loop if I can't make a non-increasing sequence, How to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: instead of the while, you know rotating more than 4 times (in your example) is useless and can be done with a for loop. Also, instead of finding the first rotation that is less, you would want to find the largest rotation that is less than the previous.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Consider a string of a big number for example s[100000];

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to solve this:

- rotate the first number to the largest possible value.

  e.g. for the number `1894` there are 4 possible rotations: `{1894, 8941, 9418, 4189}`. The largest one is `9418`.
- for the rest of the numbers rotate them to the largest possible value that is equal or less than the chosen rotation for the previous number. If there is no such rotation then sequence is not possible.

For your example:

- `1934`: the largest rotation is `9341`
- `7815`: the largest rotation `<= 9341` is `8157`
- `1894`: the largest rotation `<= 8157` is `4189`
- `6518`: the largest rotation `<= 4189` is `1865`
- `3281`: the largest rotation `<= 1865` is `1328`

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: @KakashiSasuke where are you having problems?

Comment: Rather than writing code, perhaps a diagram would be more explanatory.

Comment: @KakashiSasuke I am sorry, I am not going to spoon feed you the answer. I believe that I gave you an algorithm you can try to implement. You need to try it yourself.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I would better understand if it is explained in code.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by rotate the first number to the largest possible value!